# I have a nginx client_max_body_size setting issue with elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying with elasticbeanstalk with codePipeline.

I have to increase file size be uploaded,
so I add 02_nginx.config file is my app  directory (.ebextensions).

Here is my -2_nginx_config

```
#Elastic Beanstalk configuration for  413 Request Entity Too Large:.


container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:`enter code here`
  command: "sudo service nginx reload"

  files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf" :
  mode: "000644"
  owner: root
  group: root
  content: |
  client_max_body_size 100M;
```

and there is a issue when deploy it.
Here is the message:

> Deployment completed, but with errors: Failed to deploy application. The configuration file .ebextensions/02_nginx.config in application version code-pipeline-1600053611774-BuildArtifact-5e317627-6a37-4548-aa47-f6d4ebb03e2f contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while scanning a simple key in "<reader>", line 13, column 3: client_max_body_size 0; ^ could not found expected ':' in "<reader>", line 14, column 1: ^ , JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (#) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.

What is  problem?

Answer (score 2):

The `nginx` setting you are trying to use (`/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf`) is for **Amazon Linux 1**.

Since you are probably using **Amazon Linux 2** you should be using different files for setting nginx. For AL2, the nginx settings should be in `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not in `.ebextentions` as shown in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

Therefore, you could have the following `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with content:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

Also you don't need to restart the nginx if you use `.platform`. So basically, replace your `my-2_nginx_config` with the `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf`

Comment: i have to make .platform/nginx/conf.d/ in my app directory?
and then i should make myconfig.config?

Comment: @김기현 Yes. Just check if you are using EB platform based on Amazon Linux 2, not the old ones based on Amazon Linux 1.

Comment: yeah i checked my linux is 2.
first. i make directory in my app platform/nginx/conf.d/ 
next, i write the "client_max_body_size 100M";
is that all in the myconfig.conf? 
i meand, just writhe  the ""client_max_body_size 100M;", not anything else

Comment: first. how can i check my linux is 1 or 2?
And i think my linux is 2. and i deployed it sucessful. how can i check .conf file is successfully working? the upload sizing issue is still not solved..

Comment: @김기현   Best is to ssh into the instance and check the nginx settings from there. EB console for your env will show your platform version under its logo on the right.

Comment: yeah  my version was 2..
and then i check /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, my .conf file  is not applied...

Comment: @김기현 please double check all the paths and folders. In your first comment you wrote "i have to make .platform/nginx/conf.d/ in my app directory? and then i should make myconfig.config". The file has wrong extension. Please check my answers and use correct extension.